# how to select table view pending by default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectrequest" ng-model="selected request" ng-change="vm.selected_requested()">
    <option value="pending" > Pending </option>
    <option value="approved"> Approved </option>
    <option value="rejected"> Rejected </option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
vm.model=[{
    name:'abc',
    lastname:'xyz',
    status:pending
}]
```

//need to select pending items by default
    vm.selected_requested = function (){

```
}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420490/angularjs-filtering-values-based-on-selected-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have implemented this functionality as you requested. Now you can see the samples of filtering from view as well from controller. Let me know if you need any further help

```js
  var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []); 
       mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope,filterFilter) {
        var vm = $scope;
         $scope.model=[{ name:'abc_pending', lastname:'xyz', status:"pending" },
                     { name:'abc1_pending', lastname:'xyz', status:"pending" },
                     { name:'abc2_approved', lastname:'xyz', status:"approved" },
                     { name:'abc3_rejected', lastname:'xyz', status:"rejected" }];   
         
         vm.filteredArray = []; 
         vm.selected_requested = function (){
           vm.filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.model, {status:$scope.selected_request});
        
         }
          });
```

```html
<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
      
      <div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "studentController">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectrequest" ng-model="selected_request" ng-change="selected_requested()">
                    <option value="" > All </option>
                    <option value="pending" > Pending </option>
                    <option value="approved"> Approved </option>
                    <option value="rejected"> Rejected </option>
                </select> 
        <div ng-repeat = "temp in model | filter:(!!selected_request || undefined) && {status: selected_request} ">
           <span ng-bind ="temp.name">
             </span>
           </div>
        <br/>
       Items in filtered Array <br/>
     <div ng-repeat = "temp in filteredArray">
           <span ng-bind ="temp.name">
             </span>
           </div>
      </div> 
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to get it selected pending by default. i have edited my code. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular filter in the selected_requested function to filter the item based on selected option. Or else you can create the custom filter using $filter. Refer to the document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
    angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', []).
        controller('FilterController', ['$scope','filterFilter', function($scope,filterFilter) {
          $scope.data=[]; //use your table data.
         vm.selected_requested = function (){


          $scope.filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.data, {status:selected request});

} 
        }]);
```